# Operation with mutiple conditions in r

Tags: r

I need to compute the denominator of the [Balassa Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balassa_index), i.e. for each country `i` I need to compute `sum(x_kj)/Xj` for every country `j =/= i` and every year (`time`), where `k` is the sector considered and `X` is the sum across all sectors. My dataset looks like the following

```
Country <- c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Korea", "Korea", "Korea", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway")
id <- as.numeric(as.factor(Country))
Time <- c("1990", "1991", "1992","1990", "1991", "1992", "1990", "1991", "1992")
x_k <- c(124,144,135,122,111,231,423,444,441)
X <- c(1000, 1003, 1005, 1409, 1419, 1359, 4250, 4345, 4681)
df <- cbind(Country, id, Time, x_k)
df2 <- cbind(Country, id, Time, X)
df
df2
```

where `df` is the data for sector `k` and `df2` is the dataframe for the sum across sectors. I am using this code:

```
df$denominator <- NA
for (i in 1990:1992) {
for (j in 1:max(df$id)) {
if (df[,"Time"] == i & df[,"id"]== j) { 
    if (df[,"id"] != j & df[,"Time"] ==i) {
      df[j,"denominator"] <- sum(df[,"x_k"], na.rm=T) /df2[,"X"]
   }                                                      
  }
 }
}
```

It gives me 50 warnings of the same kind, i.e. `In if (df[, "Time"] == i & df[, "id"] ==  ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Looks like I am missing something (making a mess, actually) but I don't get what

EDIT

this is an example of what I need, using the data above.

For Italy in 1990 I want the sum of `x_k` for Korea and Norway in 1990, over the sum of `X` for Korea and Norway in 1990. Similarly, for Korea in 1990 I want the sum of `x_k` for Norway and Italy in 1990, over the sum of `X` for Norway and Italy for the same year. This is way the apparently contradictory statements in the code i tried to set up. So: for Italy in 1990, the denominator will be `(122+423)/(1409+4250)`. For Korea in 1990 it will be `(124+423)/(1000+4250)` and so on and so forth, for each country and year.

Comment: `df[, "Time"]` selects a whole column. However, `if` just compares single values (see `?ifelse` for a vectorized version). This is where things go wrong...

Comment: I cant see how to include ifelse in what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Problem may get solved if

1. you convert df and df2 to dataframe by: `df = data.frame(df)`
2. convert columns to numeric:  `df$x_k = as.numeric(df$x_k)`
3. add X to df so that you need to use only one dataframe: `df$X = as.numeric(df2$X)`
4. Fourth line in your code says: `if(... df[,"id"]== j` ; fifth line says: `if(... df[,"id"] != j`  ;; hence no row will be selected;
5. Both fourth & fifth lines say:  `if(... df[,"Time"] ==i`  ;; why repeat?
6. Two `if` statements can be combined into one.

I am not clear what final values you want but are they as given by following code:

```
mydf = structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Italy", "Korea", "Norway"), class = "factor"), 
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), time = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 
    1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992), x_k = c(124, 144, 135, 
    122, 111, 231, 423, 444, 441), x = c(1000, 1003, 1005, 1409, 
    1419, 1359, 4250, 4345, 4681), denominator = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("country", "id", "time", 
"x_k", "x", "denominator"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

mydf
  country id time x_k    x denominator
1   Italy  1 1990 124 1000          NA
2   Italy  1 1991 144 1003          NA
3   Italy  1 1992 135 1005          NA
4   Korea  2 1990 122 1409          NA
5   Korea  2 1991 111 1419          NA
6   Korea  2 1992 231 1359          NA
7  Norway  3 1990 423 4250          NA
8  Norway  3 1991 444 4345          NA
9  Norway  3 1992 441 4681          NA



for (i in 1990:1992) {
for (j in 1:max(mydf$id)) {
    with(mydf[mydf$time==i & mydf$id==j,], 
        {
        print(sum(x_k, na.rm=T)/x);
        }
    )
}
}


[1] 0.124
[1] 0.08658623
[1] 0.09952941
[1] 0.1435693
[1] 0.0782241
[1] 0.1021864
[1] 0.1343284
[1] 0.1699779
[1] 0.09421064
```

EDIT: Based on your examples, following may the values that you need:

```
for (i in 1990:1992)
    for (j in 1:max(mydf$id))
        with(mydf[time==i & id!=j,], print(sum(x_k)/sum(x))  )

[1] 0.09630677
[1] 0.1041905
[1] 0.1021171
[1] 0.0962873
[1] 0.1099476
[1] 0.1052849
[1] 0.1112583
[1] 0.1013014
[1] 0.1548223
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) e 2), they already are data.frame and numeric. 3) I cant, since I have 15 sectors, hence i have df1 to df15. I think the real points is 4). Indeed I need exactly an operator which states point 4) without causing no selection. The result would be different with respect with your solution. I will update the question with an example to clarify what I do need.

Comment: Something Wrong. The first 3 values of the output should be  `0.09630677, 0.0962873, 0.1112583`, which are the 1st, the 4th and the 7th in your example. The 4th should instead be `0.1041905` (i.e.Korea 1990), which is the 2nd in your output. Looks like your code produces `Italy 1990, Korea 1990, Norway 1990, Italy 1991, Korea 1991, ...`